# Winforms server side consumed by ASP.NET, WCF?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, wcf

Where can I find a tutorial/sample of asp.net page consuming a WCF service that uses a winforms application server side?

Thanks

Comment: You mean WCF service hosted by WinForms application?

Comment: **How** the WCF service is hosted is totally irrelevant to the consuming ASP.NET page.....

Comment: Stop. It sounds like your ASP.NET application should consume WCF service hosted in WinForms application. WTF? It is the worst application architecture you can ever create. What do you really want to do? There must be better solution.

Comment: WCF service must use winform (application) to elaborate the response!

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Have you some alternative architecture? If so please give some tips, thank you!

Comment: @Jason: You didn't include any details about your application in your question so I cannot propose any other solution. I just say that ASP.NET application calling service hosted in WinForms application is totally wrong.

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309064/architecture-design-interaction-asp-net-site-with-server-side-win-form-applicati) I tried to explain better, please take a look!

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning two separate and independent operations:

1. Consuming a WCF service from an ASP .Net application
2. Creating a WCF service that uses a win forms application

Which of them is the actual problem? Exposing functionality as a service separates the service consumer from the service provider. The service consumer (the ASP .Net application in your case) will never need to know the service provider (the WCF application) is implementing its functionality behind the scenes. All it needs to know is the public interface exposed by the service.

**Update**

If you are new to WCF, the video tutorials available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) might be a good starting point. They present you the basic knowledge of exposing as well as consuming a service with WCF.

Now, related to "that uses a winforms application server side". I assume that what you are trying to do is expose in the service some of the functionality available in the win forms application. If that is the case all you have to do is reference the exe of the forms app (with Add reference in Visual Studio) inside the WCF app and call all the needed methods from there.

Even cleaner from an architectural perspective would be to separate the user interface (UI) and business logic (BL) of your win forms application in separate projects, which will result in separate binary files after compilation (an exe file corresponding to the UI and a dll for the BL). Then you will only need to reference the BL corresponding dll in the WCF service.

Comment: Im new to WCF so both point are for me obscure! But I think point 1 is quite easy respect point 2.
And yes, my service returns image (byte[]) that are taken using winform server side (we have a virtual dedicated server to do that). So my problem is to create a WCF server that uses winform in a multithreading envirorment! Any suggestion/link/tutorial is really appreciated!

Comment: @JasonMenny, before updating my answer again, what you are saying is that you have an application that captures images and you then have to expose those images through a WCF service? Isn't the win forms app just storing the images somewhere (file system or database)? Couldn't your service just take the images from there?

Comment: Exactly, and client sends some command to service in order to receive the correct image created runtime by server side winForm!

"that uses a winforms application server side" means that the service has to create and launch (form.Show()) one windowsForm for each user, that's because I want to take a snapshot and my winform works with OpenGL so it must draw something into the screen in order to save it. I had already anything about this part so I think I've just to link my library to the service and use it from there, am I wrong?

Comment: @JasonMenny, could you please provide more info on the context on which you are going to use the applications you are trying to setup? Does the service also have to command when the application is captured or only return already captured applications?

Comment: For each request from ASP.NET page I have to send commands to my service that redirects these commands to its winform application that create an image (using OpenGL) this image is then send back to asp.net client to be shown.

Comment: @JasonMenny, a potential solution for your needs is to host the WCF service from the win forms application that captures the images. This is called self hosting and you can find a quick example here http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Self-hosting-WCF-Services/ . The win forms application will have to be always on since it will both serve the purpose of capturing images as well as being a WCF service. Is this solving your particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, This is what you need to do:

1. Create a Solution with a ASP.Net project in it. (Project **A**)
2. Go to **File > Add > New Project** and add a Windows Forms application. (Project **B**)

So, now you have two projects in your solution,

3. Add a reference from project **B** to project **A**.
4. Add a method that returns the main form of project **B** in Program.cs, here is an example:

   ```
   public static class Program
   {
       public static MainForm mainForm;
       [STAThread]
       public static void Main()
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           mainForm = new MainForm();
           Application.Run(mainForm);
       }

       public static MainForm RunForm()
       {
           Main();
           return mainForm;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Define a new Thread in **Global.asax > Application_Start** to call the **RunForm** method and store the result in a static variable. example:

   ```
   public static MainForm mainForm;
   public void Application_Start()
   {
       new Thread(
           () => { mainForm = Program.RunForm(); }
           ).Start();
   }
   ```

(Don't forget to use `using B;`)
(If you don't run the form application in another thread, your website doesn't load.)
So, now you can access the main form using **Global.mainForm**
You can define some methods for showing MessageBox in MainForm class, and call them from the website! (The form doesn't need to be shown at all)